# Sensu URL check from central to a group of servers

Tags: sensu

We have around 100 web servers that need to be checked for, 
hitting on port 8888 on each from the sensu server 
(the check can not be from the client as it need to be done from the outside.)

ACan anybody point the best practice  to agregate said group of servers to a stand alone check on the sensu server?

Thanks!

Comment: The sensu server can also run a client. Then make the check run on only that client.

Answer (score 1):

As the comment says (I cannot comment yet on ServerFault), you can install the check in the machine acting as Sensu server, and from there test the 100 web servers. If you manage your infrastructure with something like Chef (you should, is awesome), you could easily obtain in runtime the list of the 100 web servers.